# Unable to find full path g++ and gcc

Tags: linux, eclipse, gcc, g++

I am trying to install Eclipse Helios on Linux and  I manage to get eclipse installed. However, upon running a simple hello world program, errors occurred. It says unable to find full path for g++ and gcc and thus I am unable to run the program.

Does it got to do with my linux installation or eclipse installation? Please advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, Possibilities are either you didn't installed g++ before (or after) installing eclipse or the path was not detected by eclipse. Since Eclipse's installation itself does not include g++ you need to install it separately using terminal.

Also as you didn't mention which Linux are you on, I am assuming Ubuntu/Debian.Now you need to check whether g++ is installed or not on your system.To do this:
Open Terminal by pressing CTRL+ALT+T and then enter the following command

```
g++ <some c++ filename and path> -o output
```

and press enter.If it compiles that means G++ is installed else it'll say command not found.In case you don't have g++ installed use this command (this is ONLY for UBUNTU and its derivatives)`

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Also in case of previous broken installation, first use this command`

```
sudo apt-get autoremove g++
```

and then install!
Now to get the path of the newly installed compiler use this

```
$ which g++
```

and put the output path in Eclipse preferences

Answer (score 2):

first of all title is misleading, i will recommend to change it to get better answers.
check where your g++ and gcc executable are located:
Terminal:

```
$ which g++
$ which gcc
```

output is likely gooing to be:

> /usr/bin/g++

and

> /usr/bin/g++

(in this point if you get a path for gcc/g++ your linux installation is likely ok and eclipse can't find gcc and g++)

then go to eclipse yourProject > properties and set path/command for gcc and g++.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed gcc? If you have installed, maybe you should configurate eclipse? It might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On RHEL 7.3 you can do this to install the 64-bit `gcc/g++` compiler:

```
$ yum install gcc-c++.x86_64

$ g++ --version



g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```